# What is the difference between a World Space Normal VS a Tangent Space Normal?

Tags: c++, optimization, rendering, linear-algebra, bump-mapping

Figured I'd ask to get a great detailed explanation on what is the difference between a tangent space vs world space normal.

Also please include any pros and cons to either or if possible.

mainly just getting a deeper understanding as I dive more into normal mapping.

Comment: What research have you done? This seems to be a [***popular topic***](https://www.google.com/#q=world+space+normal+vs+tangent+space+normal)

Comment: I did a lot i understood the world one it was fairly straight forward but I did not understand tangent ones of course i know how you get tangent maps but I figured there's got to be some benefit to just having a tangent map over the basic world normals map. Also understand tangents are needed for bump mapping but does that mean I can just have a tangent map and skip the bi tangent tangent calculations for bump mapping if i have a bump map thats a tangent space map?